# How to avoid "(void)a" cast causing side-effects?

Tags: c++, gcc, void

I have this code and GCC prints "what!?". How can I avoid that, so that the void cast simply has the C meaning "Ignore the lonely 'a;'"?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  template<typename T>
  operator T() { 
    std::cout << "what!?";
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  (void)a;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Isn't it allowed to specialize the template function with `void`? (with empty body)

Comment: Note that in C if the `a` object is volatile qualified you will also have a side-effect with the statement `(void) a;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you've observed, this is a [bug in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54165).  The standard reads:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 12.3.2 Conversion functions [class.conv.fct]
>
> (1) A 
>   conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) object to [...] (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) void.
>   116) A conversion to void does not invoke any conversion function (5.2.9).
>
> #### 5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]
>
> (6) Any expression can be explicitly converted to type cv void, in which case it becomes a discarded-value 
>   expression (Clause 5).

As a workaround, you could write:

```
a, void();
```

It's impossible to overload `operator,(void)` so there is zero chance of this invoking user-defined behaviour from a conformant implementation.

Comment: "It's impossible to overload `operator,(void)` [...]" What if the compiler is buggy? :P

Comment: ...or to put it somewhat differently, there's zero chance of needing the workaround for a conforming implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I can't imagine I haven't hit this before.

Answer (score 8):

Adding an

```
operator void() {}
```

takes care of it.